# POCO Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, orm, poco

What is the importance of POCO support in Entity Framework?

Maybe its better to ask What is the uses of POCO ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Define 'poco'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250001/define-poco)

Comment: Go through already asked questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/725348/poco-vs-dto http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250001/define-poco http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478081/entity-framework-4-poco-where-to-start

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka Yes, the last link covers it well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually POCO is similar to POJO (Plain old java objects) in .net world. POCOs are objects tha don't have to follow any particular conventions (implementing any interface ,extending any class,having special attributes or naming convention etc.)

Some of the persistent frameworks force us to use specific interfaces or attirbutes , abstract classes. This is not a problem as long as you are working on a project from scratch and you are choosing which framework to use but if you are working on a legacy system and want to change its data access layer to use a persistent framework , it might have a negative impact.

Answer (score 1):

Realy short:
That you have objects that didn't know anything about the EntityFramework but are bound to it (Bound to the context so that the EntityFramework can take care).